# Bold font in tex mode using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, latex

After reading many posts about the topic I decided to use the following code

```
from matplotlib import rc, rcParams
...
rc('text', usetex=True)
rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
grid.axes_llc.set_ylabel(r"$\mathbf{Im(\boldsymbol{\alpha})}$", weight='bold', size='18')
```

This gives the following error:

```
RuntimeError: dvipng was not able to process the following file:
/home/lab/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/92589d6907b2844de9b825e2eaeaa998.dvi
Here is the full report generated by dvipng:
```

The report is empty! I tried already adding the latex directory to the path. I'm using python 2.7 on ubuntu. How can I make it understand the "\boldsymbol" command? or is there anything else I can do to make greek fonts bold?

Comment: It's probably easier for us to help, if you turn this into a [mcve]

Comment: I can't reproduce that error using either `plt.text` or `ax.set_ylabel`. Are you sure it isn't a problem with your LaTeX environment?